# vba to send gmail with excel

Tags: excel, vba, smtp, gmail

I have only written very basic vba code before so I know a little bit and I can usually figure out what most code is doing when reading it, but what I want to do now is beyond my abilities.  I have found some base code off of google searches and put some tags in to describe what I want with each line.

Basically, if you look at the below image of an excel worksheet, I want to click on a students name and hit a button (or something) that will generate an email in gmail that lists all the assignments that student is missing.

[missing assignments workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnnPy.jpg)
[image]

Thanks for any help!

```
Sub email()
Const username = "me@school.org"
Const password = "password"

Dim objEmail, objConfig
Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

objEmail.From = "me@school.org"
objEmail.To = "me@school.org" 'I want the To address to be loaded based on a cell in the selected column'
objEmail.Subject = "missing assignments"
objEmail.cc = "advisor@school.org" 'I want the CC address to be loaded based on a cell in the selected column'

Do While Len(objEmail.TextBody) = 0  ‘I’m not sure what this line of code is doing’
objEmail.TextBody   = “You are missing the below assignments” 
‘what do I add if I then want the body of the email to be a range of cells, based on the column currently selected?’

Loop
Set objConfig = objEmail.Configuration

objConfig.Fields ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = smtp.gmail.com
'I don't know what this is for my school, we use gmail, but the address is not @gmail'
objConfig.Fields ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
objConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objConfig.Fields ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
objConfig.Fields ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
objConfig.Fields ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = username
objConfig.Fields ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = password

objConfig.Fields.Update

objEmail.Display 'I want to display before sending

Set objEmail = Nothing
Set objConfig = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: We don't know what your schools SMTP details are either.  You'll need to speak to someone in the IT department to find out.

Comment: Discuss how this code behaves, and how that deviates from your expectations.

Comment: Since you want to send using Gmail, you could consider putting the data in a Google Sheet and using Google Apps Script to send the data.